# Multi-tenant SaaS with Caddy and Domain Mapping Not Working

Tags: laravel, https, dns, multi-tenant, caddy

I am trying to setup a multi-tenant application with Caddy server. The application works perfectly fine on my local setup with Laravel valet; allowing me to create subdomains with https. The following configuration works on production, allowing me to create subdomains.

However, the system fails when I try to map a subdomain from client to a subdomain on my application.

I am unable to figure out if there's an error in my application OR the way I am configuring DNS.

I am replicating the entire setup on my test-domain: `layoff.wtf`

My Caddyfile Configuration:

```
{
        on_demand_tls {
                ask http://layoff.wtf/caddy/ask
                interval 2m
                burst 5
        }
}

https:// {
        tls {
                on_demand
        }

        root * /home/forge/layoff.wtf/public
        file_server
        php_fastcgi unix//run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock
}
```

This setup works perfectly to serve:

1. My main domain: `layoff.wtf` with HTTPS
2. Any subdomain: `<subdomain>.layoff.wtf` with HTTPS

#### Problem

My customer has created following subdomain on my SaaS: `waitlist.layoff.wtf`
They want to serve it via their subdomain: `support.waitlist.guru`

Here's how the DNS has been configured for `support.waitlist.guru`:

`CNAME | support | waitlist.layoff.wtf. | 600 seconds`

That way, I thought when the user types `support.waitlist.guru`, they will be served my SaaS application from `waitlist.layoff.wtf`.

However, they are being served the homepage on `layoff.wtf` and not the appropriate subdomain. You can actually type those names in browser and check.

DNS configuration for my SaaS domain: `layoff.wtf` is as follows:-
 `A | @ | 13.233.62.52 | 600 seconds`
`CNAME | * | layoff.wtf. | 600 seconds`

How do I ensure that my customers can create their subdomains and map to their domain using a simple CNAME configuration; which I have seen on multiple SaaS offerings?

### Update

After multiple attempts at fixing this; I think the issue is with the way my Laravel code handles the mapped domain. Here's what I found:

```
Route::middleware('appendSubdomainInfo')->domain('{subdomain_slug}' . '.'. config('app.primary_domain'))->group(function () {
    
    Route::middleware('subdomainAccessChecker')->group(function() {

        // All my subdomain routes go here. 
        Route::get('/check', function($subdomain_slug) {
            dd($subdomain_slug);
        });

    });
});
```

The above code throws correct output subdomain when accessed on subdomain.my.app/check; but throws 404 error when run on subdomain.customer.app/check

In summary; Laravel does receive the request; but fails to deliver correct output for a mapped domain. Works fine for a regular subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-tenant SaaS application, when you want a customer's custom subdomain to resolve to a tenant-specific subdomain on your domain, you must consider about both on the DNS level within your application and web server configuration. If your customer has set up a `CNAME` record for `support.waitlist.guru` pointing to `waitlist.layoff.wtf`, then the DNS should resolve `support.waitlist.guru` to your server's IP address.

Caddy is configured to handle requests for any domain, not just subdomains of `layoff.wtf`:

```
{
    on_demand_tls {
        ask http://layoff.wtf/caddy/ask
        interval 2m
        burst 5
    }
}

https:// {
    tls {
        on_demand
    }

    @customer_subdomains host *.*.layoff.wtf support.*.guru
    handle @customer_subdomains {
        root * /home/forge/layoff.wtf/public
        file_server
        php_fastcgi unix//run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock
    }

    handle {
        root * /home/forge/layoff.wtf/public
        file_server
        php_fastcgi unix//run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock
    }
}
```

In this setup, Caddy uses a wildcard matcher for hostnames (*.*.layoff.wtf support.*.guru) to match any subdomain of `layoff.wtf` and `support.*.guru`. You'll need to adjust the matchers based on your needs.